# No Output for MergeSort Algorithm c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, output

In my project I've implemented MergeSort, bubble sort, and sequential search algorithms, however the Merge sort is not giving any output to the console, while the others work. I've tried debugging with no real luck.

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] a)
    {
        int inputLength = a.Length;

        //sets the middle index to the total length divided by 2
        int midIndex = a.Length / 2;
        //sets the last index to the length minus one (minus one included so 
an out of bounds exception is avoided
        int endIndex = a.Length - 1;

        //left side set to the middle index size
        int[] leftArray = new int[midIndex];
        //right side set to the total length minus the middle length
        int[] rightArray = new int[inputLength - midIndex];

        //looping from zero to middle of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i++)
        {
            leftArray[i] = a[i];
        }
        //looping from the middle to the end of the array
        for(int i = midIndex; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            rightArray[i - midIndex] = a[i];
        }

        //recursively called the method to sort these two sides
        mergeSort(leftArray);
        mergeSort(rightArray);
        //this calls the merge method to put the two halves together
        merge(a, leftArray, rightArray); 
    }

    private static void merge(int[] a, int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf)
    {
       int leftSize = leftHalf.Length;
       int rightSize = rightHalf.Length;

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        
        //loops until no more elements in left or right array
        while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize)
        {
            if(leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j])
            {
                //sets the element at iteration k to the elements at i in the 
                  left half if
                //it is smaller than the right half
                a[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++; 
            }
            else
            {
                //if the right half is smaller, set element at iteration k 
             equal to the 
                //element at index j of the right half
                a[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;  
            }
            k++;//iterate K
        }
        //these account for leftover elements after the above while loop.
        while (i < leftSize)
        {
            a[k] = leftHalf[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while (j < rightSize)
        {
            a[k] = rightHalf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        
    }
```

My main method is here:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try{
        TextFileReader reader = new TextFileReader();
        int[] numberArray = reader.ReadFile("numbers.txt");
        //printArray(numberArray);
        Sorts sorts = new Sorts();
        //sorts.bubbleSort(numberArray);
        //printArray(numberArray);
        //sorts.selectionSort(numberArray);
   
        Searches searches = new Searches();
        //searches.SequentialSearch(numberArray, 897);
        //searches.binarySearch(numberArray, 9992);
        //Console.WriteLine("\n\nArray length: " + numberArray.Length);
        mergeSort(numberArray);
        printArray(numberArray);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IO Exception Found.");
        }
        
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] numberArray)
    {
        foreach(int i in numberArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
      }
     }
     }
```

This is driving me crazy because the other algorithms are working and outputting correctly, but when the MergeSort is ran it gives no exceptions or errors.

Comment: When I run this code (which I had to modify quite a lot in order to compile it---ahem ;-)), I got a (ahem again) stack overflow exception from the recursive calls to `mergeSort`. I'm not familiar with this sorting algorithm but I don't think your `mergeSort` method is correct. There is no way to stop the recursion. It just calls itself over and over and over. Please provide a minimum reproducible example for questions asking for help with debugging algorithms. The code provided here does not compile as is.

Comment: What happens when length of `int[] a` is 1? When writing recursive functions, you need to tell it on what condition met it should stop.

Comment: you need to add a base case to `mergeSort` that if `a length <= 1` it just returns `a` and doesn't recurse further.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by adding a base case for when the length is <= 1. Thanks for the help guys :)